# Separate values based on record

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-formatting

Using `awk` is it doable to separate values based on a certain record?

Let's say we have following file:

```
ACCJSH PREMIUM
I5001
7
5976
7
@#
0.2
5195
5231
0.2
@#
39
5197
39
@#
```

If we take the `@#` for example, groups will be:

```
ACCJSH PREMIUM
I5001
7
5976
7
```

and

```
0.2
5195
5231
0.2
```

and

```
39
5197
39
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set `R`ecord `S`eparator variable, either at start in the `BEGIN` section or with `-v` option:

```
$ awk -vRS='@#' 1 file
CCJSH PREMIUM
I5001
7
5976
7

0.2
5195
5231
0.2

39
5197
39
```

In the same manner you can set `O`utput `R`ecord `S`eparator.